# Cannot access local variable inside of main method of Java

Tags: java

```
public class A {
static void print(){
    int i=10;
    System.out.println("i="+i);
}
void show(){
    int j=20;
    System.out.println("j= "+j);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int f=87;
    A a =new A();
    print();
    a.show();
    System.out.println(a.f); //compile error.
}
```

}

Can someone explain why i and j can be printed but f is giving compile error when i,j and f are local variables inside a method ? Thank you all for the initial replies.

Comment: Did you notice the missing `;` also ?

Comment: f variable is not defined inside the class A... its exist on function scope so you cant access it.

Comment: @jogo the error the OP is talking about is described in the title of the thread

Answer (score 4):

`f` is a local variable within the `main` method, it is not a class-level variable in `A`.

Comment: public class A {
 static void print(){
  int i=10;
  System.out.println("i="+i);
 }
 void show(){
  int j=20;
  System.out.println("j= "+j);
 }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int f=87;
        A a =new A();
        print();
        a.show();
        //System.out.println(a.f); //compile error.
    }
}Above i and j are also local variables within method right.It can be printed.Just not clear why in main method it can't be printed ?.Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I know, and the reason for that is explained in my answer to which you are replying.

Answer (score 1):

Like other people answered `f` is local. To access it in `class` level do like this:

```
public class A {

    private int f;

    public A(int _f) {
        f = _f;
    }

    public int getF() {
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ff = 87;
        A a = new A(ff);
        System.out.println(a.getF());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be thinking f is a class level (`static`) variable in the `A` class. This is flawed; it is a local variable in your main function. To access it inside that method and print it just type `f` since it is in your method.